# Android audioRecord.read buffer concatenate to make waveform

Tags: java, android, audiorecord

Im trying to build up an audio track from the mic manually and see its waveform.

I read the buffer like this:

```
 double[] bufferSet = new double[blockSize*2]

 //in a while loop
 int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
```

Then build up a buffer of my own from the read result.

So the `bufferSet` would look a bit like this

```
//First second
j=1;

for(i=0; i<blockSize; i++) {
    bufferSet[j*blockSize+i] = buffer[i];
}

//Second Second
j=2;

for(i=0; i<blockSize; i++) {
    bufferSet[j*blockSize+i] = buffer[i];
}
```

So at this point what I hope to have is a `bufferSet` with 2 seconds long of audio. The problem is when I plot it I can clearly see at the portions where each of the 3 buffers where joined up the waveform suddenly changes.

Is there a particular order the buffer has to be filled in at? Does it go time wise from 0 (being earliest moment to the last unit (latest in time) or the other way around?

So the audio waveform looks like this (2 seconds). You can clearly see in the middle suddenly the waveform shifts so its not concatenating to the previous second of data

[image]

In all how do I read the buffer correctly so when I concatenate it with previous buffers it makes a continuous waveform in the order of the time it was taken in?

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] bufferSet = new double[blockSize*2]
//First second
j=1;
...
bufferSet[j*blockSize+i] = buffer[i];
...
//Second Second
j=2;
```

Wouldn't you want `j=0` for the 1st second, and `j=1` for the 2nd?